# BeautifulSoup.find_all is not retrieving the elements of webpage

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract data from a random website. I tried to find all the div tags with class name as simpleList. but the data is not being collected. Its simply showing an empty list.

```html
              
         </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
         <div id="locationSearchResults" class="simpleList">
             
               
               <div class="result ">
                  <span class="cell cellBorder normalWidth" onclick="document.location='/real-estate/rock-spring-ga/LCGAROCKSPRING/';">
                     <a onclick="Track.doEvent('Location Search Results', 'Select Listings', 'Rock Spring, GA');" tabindex="2" title="Listings in Rock Spring, GA" class="suggestCollapse" href="/real-estate/rock-spring-ga/LCGAROCKSPRING/"><b>Rock Spring, GA</b></a>
                  </span>
                  
                  
                     <span class="cell cellBorder normalWidth"><a onclick="Track.doEvent('Location Search Results', 'Select Homes for Sale', 'Rock Spring, GA');" title="Homes for Sale in Rock Spring, GA" href="/real-estate/rock-spring-ga/LCGAROCKSPRING/">56 Listings</a></span>
                  
                  
                  
                  
                  
                     <span class="cell cellBorder normalWidth disabled"><a onclick="return false;" title="Rentals in Rock Spring, GA" href="/real-estate/rock-spring-ga/LCGAROCKSPRING/?ty=3">0 Rentals</a></span>
                  
                  
                  
                  
                     <span class="cell cellBorder normalWidth disabled"><a onclick="return false;" title="Agents in Rock Spring, GA" href="/real-estate-agents/rock-spring-ga/LCGAROCKSPRING/">0 Agents</a></span>
```

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get("http://www.century21.com/locationsearch.c21?
q=Rock+Spring&v=0#r=10&l=Rock+Spring&c=1")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
print(soup)
all=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"simpleList"})
print(all)
```

What would be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the HTML parser you're using.

Use `lxml` or `html5lib`.

I used `html5lib` and it works well:

```
all = soup.find('div', {'class': 'simpleList'}).findAll('div')
print(len(all))
```

It gives me 12.

**Edit:**

This table summarizes the advantages and disadvantages of each parser library:

[image: HTML Parsers]

Source: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Just a note, overriding `all` in the global scope is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("http://your_site.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml)
all = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'simpleList'})
print(all)
```